# Coinmarketcap Authenticated API error: 400 "\"value\" must contain at least one of [id, symbol, slug]",

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets Script I am Attempting to run this function and it does not seem to be recognizing my "qs: {'id': '1'}," Line

Getting result

```
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2019-07-15T06:41:31.753Z",
        "error_code": 400,
        "error_message": "\"value\" must contain at least one of [id, symbol, slug]",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "credit_count": 0
    }
}
```

My API Key is in

sheet ="Config"

Cell ="B35"

This is not the problem because if I remove the API key it gives an "invalid API error" so I know the address and API are correct.

Im expecting a result as described in the documentation here 
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest

```
function test() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Config");
    var key = sheet.getRange("B35").getValue()
    var options = {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers : {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': key},
        qs: {'id': '1'},
        json: true,
        gzip: true
    }

    var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("workingArea01").getRange('!F2').setValue(response);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params does is say you can use `qs` to pass query string data? Don’t see that anywhere. Have you tried what result you get if you just append the query string data to the URL manually?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, And thankyou very much. Appending the qs to the end of the URL has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to for the Comment.  With this Information I was able to make it work by adding the qs: data directly to the end of the url as follows

```
var options = {
               muteHttpExceptions: true,
               headers : {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': key},               
               }
var params = "?&id=1"
var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";


var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+params, options);
```